# Adicionar cor no meu quando rolar a página e remover quando chegar ao topo

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap, menu, sass

pessoal estou desenvolvendo um menu com bootstrap e ele faz o seguinte ele fica fico no topo da página e assim que o usuário rola a página para baixo ele some e quando o usuário rola para cima o menu aparece até ai tudo bem o problema é o seguinte por padrão deixei o menu com o `background-color: transparent` mais queria que quando o usuário rolasse a página para cima o menu ficasse com o fundo branco e quando o menu encostar no começo da página ele fica-se transparente de novo é possível fazer isso? segue meu código.

OBS: Meu código funciona tranquilo o problema mesmo é a cor de fundo que fica sempre transparente percebam que como meu menu não tem uma cor de fundo fica difícil de ver os links ainda mais quando tiver mais rolagem que o fundo já vai ser branco.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navigation-bar is-visible" data-nav-status="toggle">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Equiep hórus" /></a>
            </div>


            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Treinamento</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Instrutor</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Quem somos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Onde encontrar</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
```

SASS:

```
.navbar-default{
      background-color: transparent;
      border: none;

      .navbar-brand{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        width: 90px;
      }

      ul{
        li{
          a{
            color: #fff;
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
            font-weight: bold;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    .navigation-bar {
        padding:2rem 3rem 2rem;
        left: 0;
        position: fixed;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 1000;

        &.is-hidden {
          opacity: 0;
          -webkit-transform: translate(0,-60px);
          -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s,background .3s,color .3s,opacity 0 .3s;
        }

        &.is-visible {
          opacity: 1;
          -webkit-transform: translate(0,0);
          -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s,background .3s,color .3s;
        }
      }
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('Window Height is: ' + $(window).height());
  console.log('Document Height is: ' + $(document).height());

  var previousScroll = 0;

  $(window).scroll(function(){

    var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (currentScroll > 0 && currentScroll < $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
      if (currentScroll > previousScroll){
        window.setTimeout(hideNav, 300);
      } else {
        window.setTimeout(showNav, 300);
      }
      previousScroll = currentScroll;
    }

  });

  function hideNav() {
    $("[data-nav-status='toggle']").removeClass("is-visible").addClass("is-hidden");
  }
  function showNav() {
    $("[data-nav-status='toggle']").removeClass("is-hidden").addClass("is-visible");
  }

});
```

Comment: Tem como usar pontos e vírgulas na pergunta. A falta deles dificulta o entendimento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui está.. solução rápida (provavelmente pode ser melhorada), mas já serve para você ver como poderia fazer..

Alterei o código para utilizar o JQuery, talvez fique mais claro como você pode utilizar.

```js
'use strict';

var onTop = false;

// JQuery
$(window).scroll(function() {
  let scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
  
  if(scrollPosition < 10 && !onTop) {
    onTop = true;
    $('.navbar').addClass('onTop');
  }
  
  if(scrollPosition > 10 && onTop) {
    onTop = false;
    $('.navbar').removeClass('onTop');
  }
});

// Javascript vanilla
//var nav = document.querySelector('.navbar');
// window.onscroll = function (evt) {

//  if(window.scrollY < 10 && !onTop) {
//    nav.classList.add('onTop');
//    onTop = true;
//  }
  
//  if(window.scrollY > 10 && onTop) {
//    nav.classList.remove('onTop');
//    onTop = false;
//  }
//};
```

```css
.navbar {
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: blue;
  position: fixed;
  transition: background-color .4s ease-in-out;
}

.onTop {
  background-color: transparent;
}

html {height: 1000px}; /* somente para testar o scroll.. */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='navbar onTop'>
  Hello top.
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo vou testar aqui só não entendo o script eu adiciono ele ao existente ou deleto oque eu fiz?

Comment: Editei a resposta para utilizar o JQuery amigo.. talvez fique mais claro para você assim.